# Attribute get erased after initialization - kotlin

Tags: android, hash, kotlin

I'm working in a Android project using Kotlin. I have this piece of code:

```
val foo = FooClass(this) 
var colorRunning = FooClass.getProperty("myproperty")
```

and the class `FooClass` is:

```
class FooClass(val context: Context) : SomeHeritance{
    private val styles: HashMap<String, String> = hashMapOf()

override fun onCreate(context: Context?) {
    Log.e("Hash is empty here", this.styles.size.toString())

    this.styles.put("a","a")
    this.styles.put("b","a")
    this.styles.put("c","a")

    Log.e("Hash is size is 3", this.styles.size.toString())

}

override fun getProperty(someProp: String) {
    Log.e("Hash is size is 0", this.styles.size.toString()) //I don't understand why
    return styles[someProp]!!
}
```

The problem is that the `HashMap` `styles` get initialized in the `onCreate` method, but when I want to access to some of the values there from the method `getPropery` the `HashMap` is empty.

Making some tests, I could check that if I initialize the `HashMap` on the method `getProperty` the hash remains initialized.

Comment: This line `Log.e("Hash is size is 3", this.styles.size.toString())` should print 1 as size, because are your keys are equals...

Comment: sure @crgarridos It was a copy-paste matter. It's corrected. Thanks

Comment: It's very difficults to figure it aout without the SomeHeritance main code. you are surely callin getProperty before than onCreate

Comment: Where do you call the super class constructor? Did you mean `class FooClass(context: Context) : SomeHeritance(context)`? (Also notice missing `val` - only super class needs Context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your `onCreate` is not called on start. Put the init of your `Map` inside an `init` block:

```
init {
   with(styles){
       put("a","a")
       put("b","a")
       put("c","a")
   }
}
```

That way you can be sure to have the values put into the map before accessing it.

Also make sure to hande `null` values in your `getProperty` correctly. Instead of `!!` you could throw an Exception:

```
fun getProperty(someProp: String): String
        = styles[someProp] ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
```

Comment: but I can see that the `Logs` on the `onCreate` function are printed, so I assume that the function is being called